# Is it possible to change the tick labels using string text by CustomTicks package?

Tags: plotting, mathematical-optimization, physics

I want to get a high-resolution figure using Mathmatica. However, the FrameTicks are too short, and thus I installed the CustomTicks package.
With its help, I can plot good ticks. However now a new problem has arisen. I do not know how to edit the tick labels using my expected text. An example code to show my problem:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 6 Pi}, Axes -> False, Frame -> True,
 FrameTicks -> {{LinTicks[{-1, 0, 1}, {-0.5, 0.5}, 
     ShowMinorTickLabels -> True, DecimalDigits -> 0], 
    None}, {LinTicks[0, 15, 3, 2], None}},
 
 FrameTicksStyle -> {{Directive[Black, 16, Plain], 
    None}, {Directive[Black, 16, Plain], None}}]
```

I got this figure:

[image]

However, what I expected is to plot the y axis as [-1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1].
If I change the `DecimalDigits -> 1` to be `DecimalDigits -> 0`, I got:

[image]

My ideas:

(1) If I can define the `DecimalDigits` for MajorTicks and MinorTicks respectively, I should be able to solve this problem.

(2) If I can instead the tick values using string text, I can also solve this. For this solution, I know how to do this using `FrameTicks`, but I need to use the CustomTicks package because I want to plot ticks in proper length, thickness and color.

I learned the CustomTicks manual and have tried many times. I still can not solve this problem up to now.

Do you have some ideas to solve this problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `TickLabelFunction`.

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 6 Pi}, Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{LinTicks[{-1, 0, 1}, {-0.5, 0.5}, 
     ShowMinorTickLabels -> True, TickLabelFunction -> Simplify[# &], 
     DecimalDigits -> 1], None}, {LinTicks[0, 15, 3, 2], None}}, 
 FrameTicksStyle -> {{Directive[Black, 16, Plain], 
    None}, {Directive[Black, 16, Plain], None}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Hi， Jean. This is exactly what I want. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

It can be done without any additional packages. Just define the style of each tick as I did for left axis:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi},
 Frame -> True,
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, 16, Bold],
 FrameTicks -> {
   {Table[{-1 + 0.5 i,  
           (-1 + 0.5 i) 2,
           {i*0.025, 0},  
           Directive[Thickness[0.0075*i],ColorData["VisibleSpectrum"][450 + 45 i]]
     }, {i, 0, 4}], None},
   {Automatic, None}
   },
 ImageSize -> 1000]
```

[image]